# Getting passcode from my database android.

Tags: java, android

I don't really know why I am getting errors on the localobject. I have tried to change to string but got confused at the end. Any experts who can help please?

```
public String getPasscode(){

    Object localObject2 = this.db;
    Object localObject1 = new String[1];
    localObject1[0] = "password";
    String[] arrayOfString = new String[1];
    arrayOfString[0] = "1";
    localObject1 = ((SQLiteDatabase)localObject2).query("register", (String[])localObject1, "r_id = ? ", arrayOfString, null, null, null);


    if (((Cursor)localObject1).getCount() == 0)
    {
       localObject2 = "";
    }

    else
    {
       ((Cursor)localObject1).moveToFirst();
       localObject2 = ((Cursor)localObject1).getString(((Cursor)localObject1).getColumnIndex("password"));
    }
    ((Cursor)localObject1).close();
    return localObject2;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the errors are you are getting?

Comment: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object. for the localObject1[0] = "password";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why just not using string array instead of Object

I mean use

```
String[] localObject1 = new String[1];
```

instead of

```
Object localObject1 = new String[1];
```

By the way for handling your cursor create another object

```
Object localObject3 = ((SQLiteDatabase)localObject2).query("register", localObject1, "r_id = ? ", arrayOfString, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Object localObject1 = new String[1];
```

to

```
Object[] localObject1 = new String[1];
```

You aren't declaring it as an `Array`. It is saying that `localObject1[0]` is an `Object` when it should be an `Array`. You just didn't declare it properly.

[See Java Array Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)